# Angular Material: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl when creating a custom form field control

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to implement an Angular Material custom form field following this guide:
https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

But I keep having this error: ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

According to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol):

> This error occurs when you have not added a form field control to your form field. If your form field contains a native  or  element, make sure you've added the matInput directive to it and have imported MatInputModule. Other components that can act as a form field control include , , and any custom form field controls you've created.

But adding a matInput directive to the  tags does not change anything. It's like it's blind because the  tags are embedded in this new component `<example-tel-input>`

The mat-form-field:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <example-tel-input placeholder="Phone number" required></example-tel-input>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
  <mat-hint>Include area code</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

The component with the inputs:

```html
<div [formGroup]="parts" class="example-tel-input-container">
  <input class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="area" size="3" aria-label="Area code" (input)="_handleInput()">
  <span class="example-tel-input-spacer">&ndash;</span>
  <input class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="exchange" size="3" aria-label="Exchange code" (input)="_handleInput()">
  <span class="example-tel-input-spacer">&ndash;</span>
  <input class="example-tel-input-element" formControlName="subscriber" size="4" aria-label="Subscriber number" (input)="_handleInput()">
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fyeha

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation didn't mention the fact that you **should import material classes from the same entry points**, either

### main entry point:

**app.module.ts**

```
import {
  MatIconModule,
  MatFormFieldModule, // it's redundant here since MatInputModule already exports it
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule
} from "@angular/material";
```

**example-tel-input-example.component.ts**

```
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material';
```

or

### secondary entry points:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MatSelectModule } from "@angular/material/select";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { MatInputModule } from "@angular/material/input";
```

**example-tel-input-example.component.ts**

```
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzud1x?file=src/app/app.module.ts)**

### Why is it so important?

Because in order to get nested form control Angular material uses `@ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl)` decorator and `MatFormFieldControl` class should come from the same package otherwise `instanceof` will return `false`

Comment: If I could upvote this a million times I would. Crazy the error not matching the import. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I added hidden input in your `form-field-custom-control-example.component` and it worked.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput style="display:none">
  <example-tel-input placeholder="Phone number" required></example-tel-input>
  <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
  <mat-hint>Include area code</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```